# python + dataframe + count items in a single row based on boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a feeling there is a simple way to do this... I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df1 = 
    Index  A     B     C
    0      5     7     11
    1      10    7     11
```

I am trying to figure out how to:

```
df1['Index'==1][<10].count()
```

Ie, for index = 1, return the number of values that are <10. (so should return 1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the selection using [`DF.query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) as follows: (assuming you want to query the index axis which may be duplicated)

```
df1.query("Index == 1").lt(10).sum(1)      # assuming the index name as "Index"
Out[56]:
Index
1    1
dtype: int64
```

It's `.loc` equivalent syntax:

```
df1.loc[df1.index==1].lt(10).sum(1)
Out[58]:
Index
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for this. Would you mind explaining the lt part? At first I assumed it meant "less than", but doesn't look like it.

Comment: It indeed checks for the less than condition by creating a boolean logic, wherein `True` indicates sucess and  `False` failure. These `bools` can then be summed across as they symbolize the `int` 1 & 0 respectively. In `Pandas` and `NumPy` especially, comparisons involving(`<`,`==`,`>` etc) return a boolean mask as the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for this, your current attempt at indexing is a bit of an ugly syntax error.

```
In[32]: df.loc[1].lt(10).sum()
Out[32]: 1
```